# Hierarchical structure of strings in Java. What are the alternatives for a big one?

Tags: java, enums

I'm searching a good way to implement a hierarchical structure of strings using enumerator or (abstract) classes.

I will do this to organize the feature permissions of an application, because this permissions are persisted in the database and I need some way to track the features in Java code to validate the permission of the user.

I know some alternatives, like this:

```
public abstract class FeaturePermissions {

    public enum AppOne implements IEnum {

        SomeFeature("permission name 1");

        private String name;

        FeatureOne(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    public enum AppTwo implements IEnum {

        SomeFeature("permission name 2");

        private String name;

        AppTwo(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }

}
```

And I can call using:

```
FeaturePermissions.AppOne.SomeFeature.getName()
```

But I would like to separate the AppOne and AppTwo in different enum files but keeping the call above, because this enums will be really big in the future (like 200 entries each one).

I will use this in the code in two situations.

1. Annotation: `@HasPermission(FeaturePermissions.AppOne.SomeFeature.getName())`
2. Conditional: `if(user.hasPermission(FeaturePermissions.AppOne.SomeFeature.getName())`

What's the best way to do this? And if I need more "levels", like `FeaturePermissions.AppOne.BigFeature.SomeFeature.getName()`, what's the best strategy?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a bad design that won't scale well.

Comment: @duffymo, and it's not a good design. But these permissions, today, are all over the code and duplicated. I'm trying to put together them, but I'm accepting other solutions :)

Comment: I'd consolidate it into a FeatureManager class, encapsulate the choice of using a Map to store them, and maintain the values in a relational database.  You'll be able to add/remove properties without having to modify and redeploy the code.  Another question to ask is what you're doing with all those features?   What has to be so dynamic?

Comment: @duffymo, but how could you control the access for some method without the permission name in the Java code? I edited my question to provide more information. This permissions exists to control the access for some features or actions inside the features (update, delete, authorize something, etc).

Comment: You're venturing into security and permissions, not just features.  That's more complex than your features scheme.  I'd look into the pattern of user-group-role.  You'll have to have some kind of credential scheme.  What are you using?  A relational schema?  Or an LDAP?  Your question is becoming very broad.  It might not be a fit for SO.

Comment: @duffymo, yes, you are right. This permission framework is already done and working in the application, it's not the subject of my question modify it. I'm just worried right now about this string permissions all over the place in the code.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest using Maps. You can nest Maps, and its easy to store them as json in many databases. This will save you writing a lot of boilerplate code.

You can use a HashMap and String keys, or an EnumMap and enum keys.

Comment: If you store a map as a blog (or JSON) in the database, you may lose all ability of the database to query these values. Maybe your database can see into the JSON structure, last time I checked, mine could not. Seems like an anti-pattern to me.

Comment: @Robert: nowadays all modern DBMS support JSON. And in Postgres you could even store the Map directly into a `hstore` column. But the question nowhere mentions storing that in a database in the first place.